# Parsing with Python

Tags: python, parsing, csv, readlines

I am attempting to parse a file. Currently, I have this file:

```
word1 52345325
word2 12312314
word3 7654756
word4 421342342
```

I am attempting to store `word1` `word2` `word3` and `word4` into an array and the numbers adjacent to those words into another array.

So if i say `a[0]` i should get `word1`, and if I say `b[0]` i should get `52345325` and so on.

I was thinking about making a key-valued pair dictionary object but that may be a little complex at this point as I am just getting into python.

I currently am doing this but of course, it ain't working :P

```
def csvStringParser():
    a = {}
    b = {}
    i = 0
    f = open('/Users/settingj/Desktop/NOxMultiplier.csv')
    for line in f.readlines():
    reader = csv.reader(line.split('\t'), delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader:
            #print '\t'.join(row)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            #print i                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            a[i] = '\t'.join(row)
            b[i] = '\t'.join(row)
            print a[i]
            print b[i]
            i+=1
```

This is honestly my first hour of using python. I could easily do this in C++ but I'm am currently just trying to learn python to understand it's greater benefits/simplicity over c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv

a = {}
with open('/Users/settingj/Desktop/NOxMultiplier.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        a[row[0]] = row[1]
print a
```

For two arrays:

```
a = []
b = []
with open('/Users/settingj/Desktop/NOxMultiplier.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        a.append(row[0])
        b.append(row[1])
print a
print b
```

of even just similar solution with the zip:

```
with open('/Users/settingj/Desktop/NOxMultiplier.csv') as f:
    a, b = zip(*csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t'))
print a
print b
```

Comment: haha amazing... dam easy... You get a vote up for copy and paste code, but I am still wondering, how would I create 2 arrays instead of one that are mapped to one another like how I explained in my questions?

Comment: In the end, I feel like the first answer is my final desired goal, but I am not able to use it..

Comment: Added two arrays example.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, in fact, there is only one line of code:

```
a, b = zip(*(map(lambda x: x.rstrip('\n\r').split('\t'), open('file.csv').readlines())))
```

Some links:

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: your answer is perfect for a dictionary solution like how I specified in the question, and it's so compact :) I like it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my implementation that does what you describe with the input you describe:
    #!/usr/bin/python

```
def csvStringParser(filename):
    a = []
    b = []
    f = open(filename)
    for line in f.readlines():
        tok = line.split()
        a.append(tok[0])
        b.append(tok[1])
    print a
    print b

if __name__=="__main__":
    csvStringParser('temp.txt')
```

You could use other separators in `split()` such as `split('\t')` if you use tab delimiters, but you probably don't need the csv package for what you describe.

Comment: this is basically the same as the accepted answer but you get a vote up since it works :)

Comment: Yeah, I saw the accepted answer after I posted mine. Glad you got a working code sample.